# Best way to detect changes in the dataBase and change it in Android?

Tags: android, database

I want to do some changes in the app and I want to know what is the best way to do it. That I want to do is this: I have one activity with some buttons with the business prices. I want that the app can detect the change in the server and then updated the content in my buttons.

If you can add some reference or tutorial, will be perfect!!

Comment: There are various database technologies that implement this for you like Couchbase Sync or Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is using some push notifications, like [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). You can also check the prices every x minutes, but it is really bad way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the prices in a Catalog, and some certain time or every time the app starts or resume, it can go to the server and update the prices, in case it is out of internet you can set the last prices it has and a warning that prices are not updated..